# How to change Object on javascript to echo this "object" on base url

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to echo this array data ,i save on obj.format . but i cant echo this obj.format to url . script like this

```
$(".monitor").click(function() {

  $("#list-format").html("");
  let nama_puskesmas = $(this).data('nama');
  let id_puskesmas = $(this).data('id');
  let nomor = $(this).data('nomor');
  let base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'

  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_data',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id_puskesmas: id_puskesmas
    },
    success: function(response) {

      $.each(response, function(i, obj) {
        $("#list-format").append("<li>" + obj.format + "</li>");
      });

      $("#title-modal").html(nama_puskesmas);
      $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
      $("#button-submit").html(`<a href="${base_url}dinas/view_monitor/${id_puskesmas}" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Lihat data</a>`)
      $("#button-submit2").html(`<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini$(obj.format)" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`)
    }
  })
})
```

in this script we have obj.format .

$.each(response, function(i, obj) {
        $("#list-format").append("

" + obj.format + "

");
      });

i will echo this data to this link href (on last words before id="submit_modal"):

$("#button-submit2").html(`<a href="https://wa.me/${nomor}?text=Laporan%20Yang%20Masih%20Belum%20Lengkap%20Adalah%20Sebagai%20Berikut%20Ini$(obj.format)" id="submit_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim Pesan</a>`)

[this is obj format . i need moving it to #button_submit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLkoz.png)

Comment: Please explain your problem in a lot more detail. It is not at all clear what you are currently asking or having problems with

Comment: What does obj.format output look like in text format?

Comment: i update my question sir. i just want to echo data in obj.format into link href . but i dont know how to do this

Comment: my problem is i dont know how to echo data from obj.format to any link href